# How can I use tenant id, client id and client secret to connect to and manage directories and files in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-storage

I want to upload files in azure blob storage gen2. But problem is not able to connect using tenant id, client id and client secret. I am referring Java code given in document `->` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#upload-a-file-to-a-directory.

```
static public DataLakeServiceClient GetDataLakeServiceClient
    (String accountName, String clientId, String ClientSecret, String tenantID){

    String endpoint = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
        
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(clientId)
    .clientSecret(ClientSecret)
    .tenantId(tenantID)
    .build();
           
    DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
    return builder.credential(clientSecretCredential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient();
 }
```

But getting error for endpoint at last line of above code.

From Postman:

```
URI http://localhost:8081/upload/
Request param : <file to be uploaded>

"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/core/implementation/util/ImplUtils"
```

Comment: Seems some issue due to SAS token error is coming from DataLakeServiceClientBuilder::endpoint() but not sure why !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Azure data lake gen2 vai Azure AD auth, we need to assign a special Azure RABC role (`Storage Blob Data Owner`, `Storage Blob Data Contributor` and `Storage Blob Data Reader`) to the sp or user.  For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model#role-based-access-control-azure-rbac).

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the sp at the storage account level

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' \
    --scopes /subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

2. Code (download file)

```
String clientId="<sp appId>";
        String ClientSecret="<sp password>";
        String tenantID="";
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(ClientSecret)
                .tenantId(tenantID)
                .build();
        String accountName="";
        DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient  = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
                 .credential(clientSecretCredential)
                 .endpoint("https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net")
                .buildClient();

        DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient =serviceClient.getFileSystemClient("test");
        DataLakeFileClient fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("test.txt");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        fileClient.read(outputStream);
        byte[] data =outputStream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("The file content : "+new String(data));
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Jim, I am trying to test this from Postman tool but getting 401 unauthorized. Need to add some key ? Can this be handled from the code ?

Comment: How can I authenticate endpoint and then upload or download files ?

Comment: @javageekssb, regarding the issue, you can use Azure AD client credentials flow to get token then call azure blob rest API with the token. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory